# play 2.6 add/read request attributes

Tags: scala, playframework, request, playframework-2.6

I am trying to implement authentication for my API. I have created a filter that will load the current user based on the token.

The loading of the user works(Removed it from the example), but now I want to add the user to the request attributes so I can access it in an action or controller. But I can't get it to work:

```
package filters

import java.util.UUID
import javax.inject.Inject

import akka.stream.Materializer
import play.api.libs.typedmap.TypedKey
import play.api.mvc.{Filter, RequestHeader, Result}
import service.UserService

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

class LoadUserFilter @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Filter {

  override def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result]) (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    val newRequest = requestHeader.addAttr(TypedKey.apply[String]("user"), "test")
    System.out.println(newRequest.attrs(TypedKey.apply[String]("user"))) // attribute not found....
    nextFilter(newRequest)
  }
}
```

This is the exception I get:

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: user
```

For some reason the attribute is not added... I am using the updated request but it still doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to extract user id from the request header. I am not sure if Filter is a good place for that purpose. This can be done in different ways, I have chosen ActionBuilder and ActionTransformers for that. See [Action Composition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaActionsComposition) on Play Framework website.

First you need a RedirectingAction. Then I extract token through TokenExtractAction, user Id through UserIdExtractAction, and check auth in PermissionCheckAction.

This way it is composable, performant and reuseable. In your controller, instead of Action, use SecureAction. Then you get all the bonus userId, token, etc for free. And if auth fails, it fails silently and without cluttering your controller. This is based on the example I remember seeing on Play's website. But I had to extend it. Among the alternatives presented there, I found this one to be most useful for authenticating every REST request situations.

Also I am using an actorsystem for authentication. You can easily build one for yourself.

```
case class RedirectingAction @Inject()(parser: BodyParsers.Default)(implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext)
  extends ActionBuilder[Request, AnyContent] {

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
    block(request)
  }
}

case class TokenExtractAction @Inject()(parser: BodyParsers.Default)(
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext)
  extends ActionTransformer[Request, TokenExtractRequest] {

  def transform[A](request: Request[A]): Future[TokenExtractRequest[A]] = Future.successful {
    val token = request.headers.get(Conf.REST_AUTH_HEADER)
    new TokenExtractRequest(token, Some(TokenTool.decodeToken(token.getOrElse("invalid_token")).plaintext), request)
  }
}

case class UserIdExtractAction @Inject()(parser: BodyParsers.Default)(implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext)
  extends ActionTransformer[TokenExtractRequest, UserRequest] {

  def transform[A](request: TokenExtractRequest[A]): Future[UserRequest[A]] = Future.successful {
    new UserRequest(
      userAuthRole = TokenTool.tokenGetRoleFromToken(request.token),
      userId = TokenTool.tokenGetIdFromToken(request.token),
      token = request.token,
      plainTextToken = request.plainTextToken,
      request = request
    )
  }
}

case class PermissionCheckActionIndividual @Inject()(authSystem: AuthSystem)(implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext)
    extends ActionFilter[UserRequest] {
  implicit val timeout: akka.util.Timeout = 5.seconds

  def filter[A](input: UserRequest[A]): Future[Option[Result]] = {
    val token                = input.headers.get(Conf.REST_AUTH_HEADER).orElse(Some("invalid token"))
    val authorizer: ActorRef = authSystem.authorizer
    // verify sig and check user validity
    val res = authorizer ? CheckUserValidityFromToken(token)

    res.flatMap {
      case true =>
        Future(None)
      case false =>
        Future(Some(Forbidden("Not permitted")))
    }
  }
}


class SecureActionProvider @Inject()(val authSystem: AuthSystem, val authService: AuthService)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext,
  parser: BodyParsers.Default) {

  def SecureAction: ActionBuilder[UserRequest, AnyContent] =
    RedirectingAction(parser) andThen TokenExtractAction(parser) andThen UserIdExtractAction(parser) andThen PermissionCheckActionIndividual(
      authSystem)
}
```

in your controller:

```
def someSecureMethod = secureActionProvider.SecureAction.async ... {
   ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I now have 2 actions: `UserAction`(Loads user) and `AuthAction`(Should filter the request when there is no user). The `AuthAction` needs the user from `UserAction`. Is there a nice way to somehow extend a transform action(`UserRequest`) and implement a filter action? I don't like the andThen's very much...

Comment: And would it be smart to use a `Future[Option[User]]` for user in the `UserRequest`?

Comment: I have not experimented much about extending actions. You should check the API docs about action composition. The last action is a terminal action, an `ActionFilter`, and it filters the request based on what the `authorizer` does, along with some other checks.

Comment: The other question, in my use case, a secure method always requires a userId. But it may be refactored into being an option, why not.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like this:

```
nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
  result.withHeaders("user" -> "someUser")
}
```

Comment: I don't think that using headers as attributes is a nice solution.. Also I want to use an object instead of a string.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing like your solution. You can of course add any Serializable object into the header. I just gave an example here as a String